# c++11 double precision

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, double

Doing the following calculation:

```
double result = 58/10;
```

Will result: 5.7999999999999998

I know c++ will round it on further calculations or printing, but I need to compare output with where rounding doesn't occur so I can't have rounding happen because that may just lead to differences in other places in the output.

Is there any way to improve the precision of such calculations and having 58/10 result 5.8?

Comment: I would have thought it would result in 5 because of the integer division. You need to turn at least one of those numeric literals into floating-point, e.g. 58.0/10.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken . You may use functionality that stores the value in a way different to `double`; There are libraries doing something like this, but I'm not sure, if any of those work with base 10 though.

Comment: *I can't have rounding happen* -- This is not a "rounding" issue.  Floating point values when represented in binary will not have an exact representation, unless the floating point value is an inverse power of 2 (for example 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, etc).  If you don't want rounding, don't use `double` (or `float`).  Instead, find a fixed-point type, or use a third-party library that has a type that represents decimal fractions exactly.  Monetary and financial-based applications many times follow this route.

Comment: You can try some rational numbers library, such as Boost.Rational. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/4vP54a8vM.

Comment: Some alternatives are:  use binary coded decimals, use fixed point values, use integer math, use rational numbers, use a big number library.

Answer (score 0):

`5.8` cannot be exactly represented in floating point. If you are working with 2 digits precision after the decimal point, for example if you need to store monetary values, store it as "580" (e.g., 580 cents) and do your own formatting when printing.

```
printf("%d.%02d", n / 100, n % 100);
```

Alternatively store the decimal as a fraction:

```
struct Fraction {
  int numerator;
  int denominator;
};

int main() {
  Fraction f(29, 5);
}
```